# Can a function passed as an argument call a method of another class?

Tags: c++

I have some class - class1. It has a member function fun1 and fun2, which gets a pointer to some function fun3 as an argument.
Is it possible to call fun2 from outside (fun2 is public) in a way that fun3 passed as an argument calls fun1 (also public)?

I mean something like this:

```
    class class1
{
public:
    void fun1();
    void fun2( void(*fun3)() );

};

void fun3()
{
    fun1();
}

class1 a;
a.fun2( &fun1 );
```

I know that the code above won't work, but maybe it is possible to do it in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to call `fun2` from outside (`fun2` is public) in a way that `fun3` passed as an argument calls `fun1` (also public)?

Sure, as long as `fun3` can accept a pointer/reference to an object of type `class1`.

```
class class1
{
   public:
      void fun1() {}

      // Change the function type that can be
      // passed to fun2
      void fun2( void(*f)(class1& obj) )
      {
         f(*this);
      }

};

// Change fun3 to accept a reference to an object of type class1
void fun3(class1& obj)
{
   obj.fun1();
}

int main()
{
   class1 a;
   a.fun2( &fun3 );
}
```